# Batch file to copy files but exclude some files

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to write a batch file that will monitor a Dropbox folder and copy certain files to a local folder. The DB folder receives hundreds of files a day. But I want to exclude certain files.
For example:

```
Mar03-0601.ogg
Mar03-0602.ogg
Mar03-0701.ogg
Mar03-0802.ogg
Mar03-0901.ogg
```

I want to copy all files except the ones with 06. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Open up a command prompt and type: `xcopy /?` and `robocopy /?`.  They both have capabilities to exclude files.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. I will check this out!

Comment: Does xcopy or robocopy monitor the folders in teal time or do I need to schedule the batch file to run? I apologize for asking what may be silly questions. I am just learning this stuff.

Comment: @JackWhite - ROBOCOPY does have monitor options.

Comment: Ok didn't know about that one. Deleting my previous comment since it is wrong then.

Comment: Doesn't DropBox automatically sync files between the cloud and a local DropBox path on your local drive? I suppose you might want to copy files from you local DropBox folder to some other local path.